# Azure AD Conditional Access Policy - Require Security Key as Multifactor

Tags: security, entra-id

I am exploring the Security options for user signin ( specifically admin signin ) to Azure Portal and other Azure App and my requirements is specifically that the user should enter the password and then use the Security Key . I see that there is a a conditional access template which i can use but I find that this does not prompt the user for the Security Key , it does gives the option for the Multi Factor App / Authentication Code on Text - phone .

[image]

Any way by which i can just configure the policy for Password And Security Key ?

Comment: What are you referring to by “Security Key?”

Comment: A compatible FIDO2 hardware key

Comment: The conditional access policy doesn’t care what is used for multifactor authentication. It only cares if multifactor was used. The choice of how users authenticate and what secondary factors are available is a part of your authentication system. For instance, Azure MFA or ADFS. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks#available-verification-methods

Comment: They don’t make it easy to find this information. Here’s a better link that might get you closer. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted#choose-authentication-methods-for-mfa

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity ..I will go through them...they look promising